# Flag Question Migrate to Unix & Linux

Tags: feature-request, flags, migration

In the dialog for flagging questions, there should be an option for migrating the question to [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

[image: migration dialog]

**EDIT**

I'm not proposing that we replace any of the items already in the list.  I'm proposing that we simply add Unix & Linux to the list.

Comment: Why should that be one of the 5 spaces? What should it replace? Do you have [stats](http://stackoverflow.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats) to support the need?

Comment: @Oded Where is this "5 spaces" coming from?  That sounds to me like a completely arbitrary and artificial limit.

Comment: Considering Unix & Linux has only had 15 posts migrated to it in the past 90 days and it rejects 6% of the migrated questions, I don't see a strong case for adding it.

Comment: Related discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118685/should-some-communities-have-more-than-4-migration-targets

Comment: @bluefeet I posit that part of the reason for the lack of migrations is that potential flaggers of questions don't have the necessary tools to flag the questions for migration.  Indeed, I have found questions before that would be better suited for another Stack Exchange site; but when I found there was no way to flag them as such, I gave up on flagging and moved on.

Comment: Better suited for another site does not mean that they are off topic elsewhere and should be migrated.

Comment: @JoeW Perhaps I didn't word that the best.  I believe the argument still holds nonetheless.

Comment: It would be nice if one could select any of the StackExchange sites where a question might be better suited, but there is a realistic limit if we wish to have a concise UI. Coming up with a solution for how we would handle all of the additional migration options is the challenge, and one that could easily be a new question.

Comment: Have you considered to ask if that site wants questions to be migrated from stack overflow? It could very well be that they would prefer that questions are not migrated.

Comment: @Sildoreth If you find a question that belongs on another site, then you use an "other" flag and explain why you think it should be moved. A moderator will review the flag and decide to move it or not.

Comment: Please, don't take the status quo as an argument against a change. The lack of a migration option along with the lazyness of people might explain the low number. I, too, will never ever flag for moderator attention for a migriation to unix & linux and instead just flag as offtopic because I know it takes a moderator to handle it. If there was a migration path, I would have used it around 5 times in the last 90 days possible increasing the moved questions by a third.

Comment: @martin Why would you never flag for it for moderator attention?

Comment: @bluefeet Mostly, it's the feeling that I'm bothering a moderator with the task. I'm somewhat unsure if I should do that or just let the community handle it. Sometimes, it's also the question of correctly judging whether the migration is worthwile. A particular case comes with migrations to softwarecs, but that is a whole different story.

Comment: @martin If you find something that is on-topic for another site and off-topic for SO, then that's exactly what you should be doing. Flag it for a moderator to review because the community can't migrate it to sites not listed in the standard migration paths. It's not a bother if you can't migrate it yourself.

Comment: @bluefeet Ah ok, I somewhat had the feeling that it should not be abused. But given that I think before flagging, that should cover it then.

Comment: @martin Just remember moderators are for things that the community can't handle themselves, this would include migration to sites not listed in the standard migration list. Just to be clear we tend to judge the questions a bit harsher to make sure they are good migrations, but since we don't migrate crap that's the point. :)